# Getting error while accessing AWS DynamoDB from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am getting the error for following boto3 code in lambda to access dynamo db table through STS credentials.
The code is below

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

# Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
# ARN and a role session name.
assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::012345678910:role/test_role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary
# credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials'] 


dynamoDB = boto3.resource('dynamodb',aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],)
test1=dynamoDB.get_available_subresources

table = dynamoDB.Table('Test1')

response = table.get_item(
    Key={
            'Name': 'ABC'
        }
    )
```

### The error stacktrace is below:

```
ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetItem operation: Requested resource not found
```

Comment: you didn't include the stack trace, only the error

Comment: Does the table exist? If so, shouldn't you define `region_name` in your dynamoDB resource object?

Comment: Getting same error even after adding region_name

Comment: Just saying, table names are case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

**First check whether Table "Test1" exists**

From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) documentation:

> **ResourceNotFoundException**
>
> Message: Requested resource not found.
>
> Example: Table which is being requested does not exist, or is too
> early in the CREATING state.

Check whether this table exists with the [list-tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/list-tables.html) command:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables
```

**Verify whether your CLI default region is the same as your table's region**

If this table does exist, check your [cli configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) to verify that you're querying in the same region that the table exists. You can check your default region like this:

```
aws configure get region
```

You can use `aws configure` to change your default settings, or specify `--region` directly on any CLI command to override your default region.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten that error often usually due to the table not existing.

Check:

1. Table exists and spelling is correct
2. You are accessing the right DynamoDB instance where your table exists
3. The role you are using has access to the table

Comment: Yes,table exists and the role has administrator access.